# NSUserDefaults, is a good practice to create local value too?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'd like to know if creating a mirror of values saved in UserDefault is a good practice or not?

For example if I store parameter "A" in UserDefault is it useful to maintain a copy of this value locally and update it when UserDefault changes?

In my app I had the necessity to frequently read parameter "A", and in this case I think it's better to read from an ivar instead of from a NSUserDefault, but I'm not sure about that so I'm asking if there is a good practice to follow.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, and there's no reason why it should be down voted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like extra work and a [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) to me.

In all my apps I've always retrieved the NSUserDefaults each time they were needed and it was never an issue.  Keeps the code short and obvious.  And if it becomes a problem, you fix it, easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

The performance is irrelevant because `NSUserDefaults` is not intended to hold much information or be used so often as to cause a performance problem.

As for code encapsulation and reuse, don't use `NSUserDefaults` directly on code that performs specific tasks unrelated to your preferences. eg: a method to colorize an image should take the user preference as a parameter instead. Use it directly anywhere else.

Comment: What does "make the dependency explicit" mean? I don't see a concrete suggestion here.

Comment: The suggestion is to copy the value from NSUserDefaults to an ivar, or use it as a parameter in a method or constructor, in cases where you use it from several places. Doing so also lets you unit test your code in isolation.

Comment: Why?  Your unit tests should use defaults just like the rest of your code.  Properly written defaults code will use constants for the keys, making it no more/less difficult to find references to that user state. As well, a local cache of the value from NSUserDefaults means you have a potential state mismatch between different parts of your app if the caches aren't simultaneously refreshed across the app.  Best not to incur this fragility until a measurable performance problem is identified.

Comment: My only concern was code encapsulation as I tried (unsuccessfully) to say in the 2nd paragraph of my original answer. I edited the answer for clarity.

Comment: I think you're making assumptions when you say that `NSUserDefaults` is not intended to be used often. Where is this stated? Unless there is a performance issue, why not use it directly?

Comment: Argh, From the beginning I'm saying don't use it directly if it decreases re-usability, (which is obvious), and because of that, and because it's for small amounts of data (preferences) it shouldn't be a performance problem.